# aws api gateway lambdaにおいて、jsonの暗号化

Tags: aws, api, aws-lambda

aws api gateway とlambdaで一通りアクセスして、関数を行うところまではできました。
ターミナルでcurl をつかって、httpsでアクセスし、オプションでjsonを渡すのですが、その時の値って暗号化されているのですか??

質問時は、暗号化はどうしているのか？というふわっとした質問でした。
コメント頂き整理できました。
質問は、https自体の暗号がされているのか？
一般的にapigatewayに投げるjsonは暗号化した内容を投げるのか？
です。
前者は、コメントもいただきまして、解決しています。ありがとうございます。
後者について教えていただければ嬉しいです。

Comment: 過去の質問について、解決した場合は[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)してください。

Comment: 質問をもう少し詳細化した方が良さそうです。もしかしたら「curlコマンドに渡す前にJSONを暗号化しておく必要がありますか？」とか、「lambda関数で受け取ったJSONの暗号化を解く処理が必要ですか？」といったことを聞きたいかのようにも見えます。

Comment: kunifさん、返信ありがとうございます。そうですね。僕が聞きたかったことは、少しふわっとしていましたね。冷静に考えればhttpsなので、暗号化されていますね。しかし、そこで、内容等を暗号化すべきというか、しているのか？というのも僕が聞きたかったことです。自分の質問を明確にできておらずすみません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWSに限らず[HTTPS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)では通信内容は暗号化されています。